# tar with "-O, --to-stdout" doesn't correctly show all files

Tags: linux, compression, tar

I've got this file structure:

```
tree .           
.
├── AAA
│   ├── a1.txt
│   ├── a2.txt
│   └── a3.txt
├── AAA.tar.gz
├── BBB
│   ├── b1.txt
│   ├── b2.txt
│   └── b3.txt
├── BBB.tar.gz
├── CCC
│   ├── c1.txt
│   ├── c2.txt
│   └── c3.txt
├── CCC.tar.gz
└── tar_test.tar.gz
```

Listing archive correctly shows:

```
tar tf tar_test.tar.gz
AAA.tar.gz
BBB.tar.gz
CCC.tar.gz
```

But my attempts to list inner archives fail...

```
tar xfO tar_test.tar.gz | tar ztf -
AAA/
AAA/a1.txt
AAA/a3.txt
AAA/a2.txt
```

What do I need to change to have:

```
tar [magic1] tar_test.tar.gz | tar [magic2]
AAA/
AAA/a1.txt
AAA/a3.txt
AAA/a2.txt
BBB/
BBB/b1.txt
BBB/b3.txt
BBB/b2.txt
CCC/
CCC/b1.txt
CCC/b3.txt
CCC/b2.txt
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tar ztf -` expects just one archive. You need one such process per archive. This can be done with `--to-command` option of the leading `tar`:

```
tar xf tar_test.tar.gz --to-command='tar ztf -'
```

From `man 1 tar`:

> `--to-command=COMMAND`
>   Pipe extracted files to `COMMAND`. The argument is the pathname of an external program, optionally with command line arguments. […]

The trick is each single file extracted by the leading `tar` will be piped to its own *separate* instance of `COMMAND`. This way you run as many `tar ztf -` processes as needed.